# Where do trades take place when the stock exchange is closed?

Tags: equities, trading

Some markets support pre-market and after-market trades. These trades take place outside the opening hours of the stock exchange. My questions are:

- If the stock exchange is closed, how and where do these after-hours trades take place?
- Who records the transactions?

Comment: Are you speaking about futures markets?  Market orders placed with equity markets after hours (eg, after close and before open) are held and executed on open.

Comment: @Chris I'm speaking about stock markets. What about limit orders and stop orders?

Comment: They're not executed if the market isn't open.

Comment: @Chris Who keeps the record of market orders placed after hours? Is it the parties involved in the trade? Or is it the stock exchange? Is the agreement to buy/sell done over the counter?